# How do I bring the button closer to the Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

as you can see in the picture, there is a huge gap between the first button, the number and the second button. I tried using and not using containers, I switched between body: Center and Listview. I pretty much want the arrows to be directly above and below the number.

```
body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 350,
              height: 36,
              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "ATH: " + highScore.toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30, color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 136, 255, 70)),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Text(
                  Score.toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30, color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 136, 255, 70)),
                )
              ]),
            ),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: PfeilHoch,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up),
                iconSize: 350,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 300, 0, 100),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              ),
            
            Text(
                (randomNumber.toString()),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90, ),
              ),
            
            IconButton(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                onPressed: PfeilRunter,
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                iconSize: 350,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(300, 0, 0, 100),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              ), 
          ],
        )
```

How it's looking right now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Listview use Column with SingleScrollChild

Comment: Thanks! So you mean like  `body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [Container(` ? In case I didnt do anything wrong, this did not really close the gap